# What is the complexity of this function?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

I always offer a solution like this in my interviews, but I am not sure what the complexity is O(n^2), O(nlogn)?

```
for(i = 0; i < limit; i++)
{
    for(j = i; j < limit; j++)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your justification for your answer?

Comment: How would it be O(N Log N)? Is there anything logarithmic about any part of it?

Comment: Well I decide it's O(N^2), but I am not sure because the second loop doesn't iterate N times?

Comment: There's know way to know the final answer without knowing the complexity of "do something", but start by determining how many times "do something" will be done.

Answer (score 2):

Just to understand, take limit as 6. Now, i can go from zero to 5 and j can go from i to 5. 
When i=0 j=0 to 5, 
     i=1 j=1 to 5,
     i=2 j=2 to 5, 
     i=3 j=3 to 5,
     i=4 j=4 to 5,
     i=5 j=5

So, the "do something" part of the program runs 5, 4, 3, 2 and 1 times. 
That means a total of 15 times for limit = 6. Or n(n+1)/2 times as sum of numbers from 1 to n is that. 
(Assuming limit is represented by n).

I see that it is not exactly n^2 complexity but as n becomes larger, n^2 term will dominate. Thus in my opinion it is O(n^2).

Comment: Not just `O(n^2)` in your opinion: "as n becomes larger, `n^2` term will dominate` is the **definition** of `O(n^2)`. So you're spot on.

Answer (score 1):

Let's analyze it.. The outer loop will run `limit` times.

```
First iteration of outer loop, i=0.. Inner loop runs limit times..
Second iteration of outer loop, i=1.. Inner loop runs limit-1 times.. 
.
.
.
.
Limit-th iteration of outer loop, i=limit-1.. Inner loop runs 1 time..
```

This gives us a complexity of `O(limit) * O(limit-1) * O(limit-2)*..*O(1)` which in turn makes the complexity of this piece of code `O(n2)`

Answer (score 0):

This complexity is of course O(N^2). Why, let's analyze this in simple way using deductive way.

```
    Limit = 10, the iterations are = 10 + 9 + 8 + 7 + ... + 1 = 10*(10+1) / 2
    Limit = 20, the iterations are = 20 + 19 + 18 + ... + 1 = 20*(20+1) / 2
    .
    .
    .
    Limit = N, the iterations are = N + N-1 + N-2 + ... + 1 = (N)(N+1)/2 
    In big-Oh notation, its complexity is O( (N)(N+1)/2 ) = O( (N^2 + N) / 2 ) which gives O(N^2)
```